# Create a Query in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
=query(LT!B:E,"Select E where D matches """&LessonPlan!A4&""" or 
 B matches """&LessonPlan!A4&""" label E '' ")
```

Would anyone be willing to tell me how to change this into google scripts? Your help would be greatly appreciated!  Have a great holiday and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this should do it:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var source = ss.getSheetByName('LT');
var outputSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var matchval = ss.getSheetByName('LessonPlan')
    .getRange('A4')
    .getValue();
var val = source.getRange(2, 2, source.getLastRow(), 4)
    .getValues();
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (val[i][0] == matchval || val[i][2] == matchval) arr.push([val[i][3]]);
}
outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
}
```

Note: the sheet where the results are written is now set to the active sheet. You may need to change that ... Hope this helps ?

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Can I bother you to accept my answer then ?

Comment: may I ask another question?  what if I wanted to also add the contents in Column D to the same row but a new column? So column E and D would display on the new output sheet....[val[i][2]       I tried arr.push([val[i][3]],[val[i][2]]); but it puts the contents of column D on a new row.

Comment: try: arr.push([val[i][3], val[i][2]])